# Stratified Sampling a Dataset and Averaging a Variable within the Train Dataset

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-caret, sampling

I'm currently trying to do a stratified split in R to create train and test datasets.
A problem posed to me is the following

> split the data into a train and test sample such that 70% of the data
> is in the train sample. To ensure a similar distribution of price
> across the train and test samples, use createDataPartition from the
> caret package. Set groups to 100 and use a seed of 1031. What is the
> average house price in the train sample?

The dataset is a set of houses with prices (along with other data points)
[image]

For some reason, when I run the following code, the output I get is labeled as incorrect in the practice problem simulator. Can anyone spot an issue with my code? Any help is much appreciated since I'm trying to avoid learning this language incorrectly.

```
dput(head(houses))

library(ISLR); library(caret); library(caTools)
options(scipen=999)

set.seed(1031)
#STRATIFIED RANDOM SAMPLING with groups of 100, stratefied on price, 70% in train
split = createDataPartition(y = houses$price,p = 0.7,list = F, groups = 100)

train = houses[split,]
test = houses[-split,]

nrow(train)
nrow(test)
nrow(houses)

mean(train$price)
mean(test$price)
```

Output

```
> dput(head(houses))
structure(list(id = c(7129300520, 6414100192, 5631500400, 2487200875, 
1954400510, 7237550310), price = c(221900, 538000, 180000, 604000, 
510000, 1225000), bedrooms = c(3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4), bathrooms = c(1, 
2.25, 1, 3, 2, 4.5), sqft_living = c(1180, 2570, 770, 1960, 1680, 
5420), sqft_lot = c(5650, 7242, 10000, 5000, 8080, 101930), floors = c(1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1), waterfront = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), view = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), condition = c(3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3), grade = c(7, 
7, 6, 7, 8, 11), sqft_above = c(1180, 2170, 770, 1050, 1680, 
3890), sqft_basement = c(0, 400, 0, 910, 0, 1530), yr_built = c(1955, 
1951, 1933, 1965, 1987, 2001), yr_renovated = c(0, 1991, 0, 0, 
0, 0), age = c(59, 63, 82, 49, 28, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> 
> library(ISLR); library(caret); library(caTools)
> options(scipen=999)
> 
> set.seed(1031)
> #STRATIFIED RANDOM SAMPLING with groups of 100, stratefied on price, 70% in train
> split = createDataPartition(y = houses$price,p = 0.7,list = F, groups = 100)
> 
> train = houses[split,]
> test = houses[-split,]
> 
> nrow(train)
[1] 15172
> nrow(test)
[1] 6441
> nrow(houses)
[1] 21613
> 
> mean(train$price)
[1] 540674.2
> mean(test$price)
[1] 538707.6
```

Comment: Please use ``dput(head(houses))`` and post the output in your question rather than posting images of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - is this what you wanted to see?

Comment: Yes thanks - that makes it much easier for people to reproduce your error and help you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks - yeah I guess it's difficult to reproduce without the dataset, but hopefully this is a simple enough scenario where someone will just spot a red flag in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to reproduce it manually using `sample_frac` form `dplyr` package and `cut2` function from `Hmisc` package. The results are almost the same - still not same.
It looks like there might be a problem with pseudo numbers generator or with some rounding.
In my opinion your code looks to be a correct one.
Is it possible that in previous steps you should remove some outliers or pre-process dataset in any way.

```r
library(caret)
options(scipen=999)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) # to use diamonds dataset
library(Hmisc)

diamonds$index = 1:nrow(diamonds)

set.seed(1031)

# I use diamonds dataset from ggplot2 package
# g parameter (in cut2) - number of quantile groups

split = diamonds %>% 
group_by(cut2(diamonds$price, g= 100)) %>% 
sample_frac(0.7) %>%
pull(index)

train = diamonds[split,]
test = diamonds[-split,]

> mean(train$price)
[1] 3932.75
> mean(test$price)
[1] 3932.917

set.seed(1031)
#STRATIFIED RANDOM SAMPLING with groups of 100, stratefied on price, 70% in train
split = createDataPartition(y = diamonds$price,p = 0.7,list = T, groups = 100)


train = diamonds[split$Resample1,]
test = diamonds[-split$Resample1,]

> mean(train$price)
[1] 3932.897
> mean(test$price)
[1] 3932.572
```

This sampling procedure should result in mean that approximate to a population one.

Comment: This helps a lot - there's a strong possibility whoever proposed this problem actually created an error in their answer. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed you set List to ```T``` and then used ```$Resample1```. Can you explain this?

Comment: Then the createDataPartition returning a list from which I could subset a vector by a name. More elegant for me than subsetting by a matrix .